# jQuery Autocomplete plugin (from Joern) not releasing when other elements clicked

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery Autocomplete plugin from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete on IE7 and it's not releasing the autocomplete when I click outside the Autocomplete input field and results.

It looks like this is a formatting bug...maybe IE7 thinks the entire form is the autocomplete section. If I click on another "focusable" element like a line of text, or another form field, or even the outer edges of the page then it goes away, but not when I click on blank elements close to the autocomplete fields (e.g. the form field)...really wierd. Anyone experience this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using DD_roundies for form borders. As soon as I removed DD_roundies everything worked fine. (DD_roundies placed an  tag around the form that got in the way of the autocompleter).

Sucks that this only messes up IE7 though, and not 8. :-/